# How to redirect one page on the subdomain

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain

Hello  I have arkansaspickem.com i want to redirect arkansaspickem.com/blog page to my subdoamin news.arkansaspickem.com  I do not have any wordpress installation over there. How can it is possible.

Comment: Is your WordPress Address *(URL)* *"arkansaspickem.com/blog"* or *"arkansaspickem.com"*?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use WordPress plugins. For example:

1. 301 SEO Redirection
2. 301 Redirects

Or use `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

Add `.htaccess` file to root folder in arkansaspicker.com.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(blog/.*)$ http://news.arkansaspickem.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Then you have two options to get contents of `/blog` to show on news.arkansaspickem.com.

- Move your WP to subdomain folder. [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/backup-wordpress/1-4-1.html) will help you with that.
- Change your subdomain's `vhost` `DocumentRoot` to path to `/blog` folder. This is usually not possible, if using shared hosting. See [VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Did you test that on a live WordPress application?

Comment: No, haven't tested it.